# How does Resolve works in case of AsImplementedInterfaces?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a simple application as shown below:

```
public interface PaymentProcessor
{
    void ProcessPayment();
}

public class PaymentProcessorOne : PaymentProcessor
{
    public void ProcessPayment()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Payment processed by PaymentProcessorOne.");
    }
}

public class PaymentProcessorTwo : PaymentProcessor
{
    public void ProcessPayment()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Payment processed by PaymentProcessorTwo.");
    }
}

public class PaymentProcessorThree : PaymentProcessor
{
    public void ProcessPayment()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Payment processed by PaymentProcessorThree.");
    }
}
```

And I'm registering my types in Program.cs as:

```
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).AsImplementedInterfaces();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    var processor = container.Resolve<PaymentProcessor>();
    processor.ProcessPayment();
```

First time when I executed this code, the output was "Payment processed by PaymentProcessorTwo". However, when I executed the same code on a different machine the output was "Payment processed by PaymentProcessorThree".

I would like to know how is autofac resolving the `PaymentProcessor` in the main logic.

Comment: And what is the behavior you need? Do you always want to have one particular implementation?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218803/is-order-of-dependencies-guaranteed-when-injecting-ienumerablet

Comment: Yeah, I would like `processor` to always have an instance of `PaymentProcessorOne`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `AsImplementedInterfaces()`, but in `.RegisterAssemblyTypes()`.

The magic of resolving types, when there are more than one type registered for interface is pretty simple - last registration wins. It means, the order of types is unknown when you use `RegisterAssemblyTypes()`, and can vary on different machines you run your code.

There are several ways to o make it work as expected, e.g. you can explicitly register your types or sort them somehow before you pass them to `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` method